fetchPriority does not exist on HTMLLinkElement
Their HTMLLinkElement model has the aforementioned property (as shown in image), but the compiler is complaining that the property doesn't exist. Oddly enough you can even see that it has one reference (the reference I am making in my component).

I have an image component that also (ideally) generates a link for image refs to emphasize fetchpriority in the document head.
Here is my code (pretty straightforward, and no red squiggles to suggest an error):
  const _link: HTMLLinkElement = document.createElement('link');
  _link.rel = 'preload';
  _link.as = 'image';
  _link.href = _source;
  _link.media = '(min-width: 0rem)';
  _link.fetchPriority = fetchpriority ?? 'auto';
  document.head.appendChild(_link);

There are some solutions out there for fetchpriority extensions on the image element itself, because natively this property doesn't exist in react. There isn't, however, from what I have been able to find, any solutions around this topic and I'm very interested to here if other people have had this issue...

Update:


Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.

I listed the error. But sure, I'll add an image anyways if it helps you.

This property isn't supported by Firefox yet, so I'm guessing the compiler probably rejects it, so that you don't end up writing code that isn't compatible with all major browsers yet ...?

Nah, browsers just disregard unsupported contents. For some reason, the contributors to React didn't even add fetchPriority to the image tag which has to be added secondary with a custom extension. I'll post the solution for my question. It's not the desirable approach, but until the React team fixes this there likely isn't much else to be done.

Not my favorite solution, but this works for now.
 document.head.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'beforeend',
    `<link rel='preload' as='image' href=${_source} media='(min-width: 0rem)' fetchpriority='high'>`
  );

